# How to install Inno setup silently

Tags: inno-setup

I tried to install inno setup silently using commandline

**setup.exe /SILENT or /VERYSILENT** but unsuccessful.

Can someone advice if there's any other way to do it..

Comment: what errors did you get? What platform

Comment: Invalid command (Error message: Please specify valid method). I was install on windows platform (Windows server 2008 64bit)

Comment: No, [`/SILENT`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=SILENT) and [`/VERYSILENT`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=VERYSILENT) parameters are the right ones to use. We would need to know more details about how, and where did you run the setup (since I don't want to believe that command prompt would return *Invalid command (Error message: Please specify valid method)* error message). Could you elaborate on how did you run the setup, please ?

Comment: I was run it from command prompt with administrator previlage by executing a command: setup.exe /SILENT or /VERYSILENT from source directory.